# C# How to properly remove event handler code?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have a `keyup` event that I want to remove from my C# Winform:

```
private void txtInputBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
      if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
      {
          cmdSend.PerformClick();
      }
  }
```

If I comment out or delete this function I get an error in the design view of the form:

> "The designer cannot process unknown name 'txtInputBox_KeyDown' at
>   line 66. The code within the method 'InitializeComponent' is generated
>   by the designer and should not be manually modified. Please remove any
>   changes and try opening the designer again."

The program also will not compile.

It happens if I try to delete any event handler code on my form. I am teaching myself C# from my background in VB.NET and in VB.NET I could remove event handler code without issue.

Comment: remove it from designer properly

Comment: in the properties window of VS check the eventhandlers of your field/textbox (the "lighting"  symbol) and remove that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

thats because in C#, the functions are added to the events programatically by the designer, when you add it in the designer.

In the solution explorer window, Expand `Form1.cs` and open the `Form1.Designer.cs` file there:

[image]

then locate the function :

```
private void InitializeComponent()
```

and delete the line that registers your event handler to the event. it will have a `+=` operator in the middle like this:

[image]

your event will be located at line 66 and will look like this:

```
this.txtInputBox.KeyDown += new System.EventHandler(this.txtInputBox_KeyDown);
```

Comment: Is this the "proper" way of doing this? It seems there would be a cleaner/faster/more official option. (Not saying it's incorrect I'm just remarking).

Comment: this is basically the proper way. the designer simply visualizes it for you, so you can remove it from the properties window under events page, but it does the same as deleting this line. whether to delete it from the designer or from the code, is up to you.

Comment: Proper way is to remove using design view by going in control properties @TravelinMax

Answer (score 4):

It is because in **Designer.cs** event handler is registered and when you just delete from code behind it's method, it does not remove it's event registration from **Designer.cs**

you should remove event from form designer view by going in control **properties** so that this issue not comes or from **Designer.cs** remove event registration line which will be like:

```
SomeTextBox.KeyUp += SomeTextBox_KeyUp
```

Answer (score 2):

In the designer code that is automatically generated by Visual Studio the event is still linked to this non-existent function.

In the Solution Explorer, find your Form.Designer.cs file (it is in a subnode under the main Form.cs), or use the Find in Solution function to find the line that says

```
txtInputBox.KeyDown += new System.EventHandler(txtInputBox_KeyDown);
```

Delete the line, and it should work again.